# Where should i store expiring REST API authentication token?

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0

We have a OAuth API which provides expiring tokens to authenticate REST APIs in our application.

**What I am trying to achieve**

While application is running on server when first request comes through, get the expiring token, expiry date from OAuth API and store in the application somewhere and use that token until that expiry date and request for another token after that.This Token should be used Globally across the application until it expires.

**What I have Done**

Setup a Method which will get token from Oauth API and writing it to web.config file as App settings with the expiry date. whenever a request comes through to hit the REST API it will check if the token is available and not expired from web.config and return the Token. if the Token is not available or expired it will  get a new token from OAuth API.

**Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Token" value="" />
<add key="ExpiryDate" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

**CS file**

```
public RESTAPI GetData()
{
string Token = GetToken();
//use this Token to Authenticate REST API
}

public string GetToken()
{
string Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"];
DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpiryDate"]);
if(Token == "" || ExpiryDate<=DateTime.now)
  {
   RefreshToken();
  }
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"];
} 

public void RefreshToken()
{
//Consider OauthObject as object returned from Oauth API with Token and expiry date
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"] = OauthObject.Token;
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpiryDate"] = OauthObject.ExpiryDate.toString();
}
```

I want one token to be distributed across the application for all users until it is expired. does it work this way if i want to do that? or any other suggestions please.

Note: ASP.Net web application written in C#.

Comment: Consider storing it in a database.

Comment: Is there an alternative to storing in database?

Comment: Yes. You could store it in a file. Or anywhere you like really.

Answer (score 2):

For .Net Core you can store the authentication token in memory using the `IMemoryCache` interface, which you can inject easily to the consumer service using the build-in DI container.

That way you can store it within memory only for the expired time span that correlated with `Expires_in`, so afterwards it will be deleted automatically.

```
class RestConsumerService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    RestConsumerService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
         _memoryCache = memoryCache
    }
    string GetOAuthToken()
    {
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue<string>("MyTokenKey", out string access_token)) //You can store the T object as well.
        {
            return access_token;
        }

        //Do Api OAuth call
        //...
        OAuthRespone response = fetchAccessToken();

        _memoryCache.Set("MyTokenKey", response.Access_token, new TimeSpan(0, 0, result.Expires_in));

        return response.Access_token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you want to store the access token in the first place. Why not just keep the token in memory while its valid?

From what you wrote, it looks like you want your application to act on its own behalf for any user. In that case, the [OAuth2 client credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) is your best option.

Also, it may be better to just use the token until the API returns an `HTTP 401` error and then renew the token and retry the API. If you store the expiration time, you have to account for clock-skew between machines. The issued token may be encrypted, in which case you cannot get the expiration time.

Comment: the token will be valid for 72 hours, and it is created using a NUID, not per user, so i have to store it and make the valid token available for web requests accesing the REST APIs